ui-api calls failing in partner sites
I get a 404 when trying to access ui-api calls on partner sites
e.g
/services/data/v57.0/ui-api/favorites
/services/data/v57.0/ui-api/layout/Contact
response
{errorCode: "NOT_FOUND", message: "The requested resource does not exist"}
The org is Enterprise edition and the users profile has API Enabled
Is there something else I should check?
Thanks
Nathan
